# What chances are to have token collision/duplication during token generation upon multi-server php app?

Tags: php

I have a table containing urls that a user can visit:

```
id PK AUTOINCREMENT
token VARCHAR (8)
user_id_visited INTEGER
visited BOOLEAN
```

The url is in the form of [https://example.com/mypage/^token^](https://example.com/mypage/%5Etoken%5E) where `^token^` is retrieved from `^token^` field above. What I want to achive it to block a user having `user_id_visited` revisit a page having the very same token.

I generate the token like this:

```
$token = bin2hex(random_bytes(5));

// Insert token in the database here
```

But my application is in 2 webserver instances writing in the same database. What I want to avoid generating the same token hence an idea is to use the server's hostname:

```
$token = gethostname()."_".bin2hex(random_bytes(5));
```

So my question is if I avoid the usage of `gethostname` what chances are to generate duplicate tokens using only the `random_bytes`?

Comment: I guess the chances to generate the exact same token are very small, but not impossible. Now the possibilities, may reduce if you don't have too much traffic on your site, or can increase if you have massive traffic. Other than bin2hex + random_bytes, did you check the use of UUID? This seems to have better uniqueness rates, and possible you never gonna get duplicate tokens. Finally, why you use two database instances? I mean, may this could be a wrong implementation?

Comment: I use 2 WEBSERVER instances and one database. @KodeFor.Me

Comment: That's totally fine then. I though you have two systems installed side by side and both have different DBs :). Then, why not querying your DB with the generated Token, to make sure doesn't exists right before you persist it? This way you can avoid having duplicates, but again, as I explained before, maybe a UUID is better solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/4xlglh/will_random_bytes_ever_repeat/), probably with `random_bytes(5)` you could have something close to 2^40 possible unique tokens, which translates to a 39% chance of collision after 2^20 = 1048576 generated tokens.

Thus, depending on the amount of entries you are going to have in your DB, the probability to have duplicates is quite big.

Maybe the best possible solution, is to modify your DB, to make it accept UUIDs, and generate UUIDs instead which has better uniqueness rates touching the 2^122 possible unique IDs.

Comment: Won't `random_bytes(5)` generate 5*8 = 40 bit length string? Hence I think the possible tokens are about 2^40.

Comment: Based on the thread: _for random_bytes(16) you have 128 random bits. By the birthday paradox, you have a 50% chance of seeing a collision after approximately 264 generated IDs._